# EF Core TPH Migration - Derived types have no key defined

Tags: entity-framework-core, fluent, table-per-hierarchy, tph, ef-core-2.2

EF migrations fails and tells me that the derived types have no key defined.

I'm trying to setup TPH, which should be fairly easy with attributes, but I can't get it to work with separate (fluent-)configuration files. It always reports that the key of the derived types is not defined.

If I define it on the derived types, then it says the key must be defined for the base type.

Entity type configurations:

```
public class CoreEntityConfiguration<TBaseModel> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TBaseModel> where TBaseModel : class, ICoreEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBaseModel> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.Created).IsDateColumn().HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(p => p.Modified).IsDateColumn().HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
        builder.Property(p => p.Rowversion).IsRowVersion();
    }
}

public class BaseEntityConfiguration<TBaseEntity, TKey> : CoreEntityConfiguration<TBaseEntity> where TBaseEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TBaseEntity> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
        builder.HasKey(p => p.ID);
    }
}

public class EventConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Event, int>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Event> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new SearchableConfiguration<Event, int>());

        builder.Property(p => p.Time).IsDateTimeOffsetColumn();

        builder.HasOne(p => p.Player).WithMany(p => p.Events).HasForeignKey(p => p.PlayerID).OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasDiscriminator(p => p.EventType)
            .HasValue<Goal>("Goal")
            .HasValue<Card>("Card")
            .HasValue<Substitution>("Substitution");

        builder.ToTableWithSchema(Constants.SCHEME_OPERATIONS);
    }
}

public class EventGoalConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Goal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Goal> builder)
    {
        builder.HasBaseType<Event>();

        builder.HasOne(p => p.GoalType).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.AssistedByPlayer).WithMany(p => p.Assists).HasForeignKey(p => p.AssistedByPlayerID).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

Model classes:

```
public abstract class CoreEntity : ICoreEntity
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Rowversion { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey> : CoreEntity, IBaseEntity<TKey>
{
    public TKey ID { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Event : BaseEntity<int>
{
    ...
}

public class Goal : Event
{
    public int GoalTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual GoalType GoalType { get; set; }

    public int? AssistedByPlayerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Player AssistedByPlayer { get; set; }
}
```

I can't get rid of this error:

[image: Migration error]

Please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong. I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: The error message refers to an entity type `Goals` which I don't see in the provided model. Also some parts of the model are missing, the code which applies configurations and also some non standard methods (`ApplyConfiguration` on `EntityTypeBuilder<>`, `ToTableWithSchema` etc.). In order to tell you what's the problem, you need to provide a full repro code (a.k.a. [mcve]).

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out... Thank You! I've found the error, it was an owned type which is supposed to hold statistical information, but it was an inner type and i didn't know that i need to chain OwnsOne-calls.